# Removing two elements of an array using .delete

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array... say

```
arr= [:a, :b, :c, :d, :b, :a, :q]
```

and I want to remove all `:b` and `:c`'s

Can I accomplish this using the `.delete` method in one line?

I know that `arr.delete(:b)` will remove `:b` and I know `arr.delete(:c)` will remove `:c`,  but how do I remove both in one line?

I tried different variations of:

```
arr.delete(:c,:d)
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 7):

IMO  you can use `delete_if` for this case:

```
array = [ :a, :b, :c ]
array.delete_if {|x| [:b,:c].include?(x) }   #=> [:a]
```

more about `delete_if` at [Array#delete_if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if)

Answer (score 4):

See [`Array#-`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-2D) (difference):

```
> [:a, :b, :c, :d, :b, :a, :q]   # => [:a, :b, :c, :d, :b, :a, :q]
> a - [:b, :c]                   # => [:a, :d, :a, :q]
```

There are other basic set operations too, e.g. [`Array#+`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-2B) (union) and [`Array#&`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-26) (intersection).

Comment: `-` does not delete from the original array
and even if we use `a = a - [:b, :c]` we will just create an extra array for no purpose. Consider the case when `a` have like millions of elements.

Comment: @sahildhankhar: You're right. OP: See his answer. That might be more suitable.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use reject! for this:

```
arr.reject!{|element| [:b, :c].include?(element)} #=> [:a, :d, :a, :q]
```